# How to write Lambda expression into method references?

Tags: java, java-8

how can we write the Lambda expression statement

```
Collections.sort(list,(a1,a2) -> (a1.getName().compareTo(a2.getName())));
```

into method references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Item::getName));
```

Or better yet,

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a lambda expression is basically the implementation of a single method defined by a functional interface.

Any method that has a matching signature (except method name), can be used by reference in place of a lambda expression.

In your case, it's the `Comparator<? super T>` interface and it's `int  compare(T o1, T o2)` method, so any method that returns an `int` and takes two arguments of the type of the collection elements will do.

So, if your list is a `List<Person>`, any method like this will work, regardless of method name:

```
public static int xxx(Person p1, Person p2) { ... }
```

The method can have any visibility (public, private, ...) and doesn't have to be static.